# Animated flag loop

Tags: animation, looping

I'm making an animated flag model for beamng.drive, and the flag animation doesn't loop when going from frame 150 to 0, and I want it to be smooth.

A [short video showing the problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZH3kofIllmQ).

[image]

File: [image]

Comment: so are you using physics or bones?

Comment: bones, forgot to say exported file is collada (dae)

Comment: so are you sure that the keyframes are the same at frame 0 and 150? Maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=omv34nqj" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/omv34nqj/)

Comment: meybe i missed 1 or 2 steps and i didnt find any solution on tutorials

Comment: actually your flag is animated by a Force Field (Wind), so you must have forgotten something in the process because I guess your bones must have a purpose like they control the flag after baking the physics, something like that...

Comment: and how can i bake phisics and save the posision of the bones from frame 0-100? then i guess will just mirror the position... and i will have the loop

Comment: if i apply cloth modification somethink wierd heppend...

Comment: what tutorial did you use?

Comment: some tutorials from youtube to make flag, but noone of them explain everything

Comment: Did you use a particular tutorial for this method because I'd like to know what you are supposed to do once the bones follow the flag, how do you save the movement of the bones and get rid of the physics so that you can loop? Another solution would be to delete all cloth physics and fake the movement with some bone movements

Comment: used this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r1w4VoVPixg , becouse its what i need to make it work in game just the export file is dae

Answer (score 2):

So in the tutorial you link he uses cloth physics for the flag simulation, then he makes bones follow the vertices of the flag, and at last he bakes the bones this way:

- Select all the bones in *Pose* mode, go in the header menu > *Pose > Animation > Bake Action*:

[image]

- In the pop-up panel, enable *Only Selected bones, Visual Keying, Clear Constraints* options, it will save all the bones positions and delete their constraints:

[image]

- Now all the movements have been baked to individual keyframes:

[image]

- Delete the flag *Cloth* physics:

[image]

- Now you still need to make the animation loop correctly, so copy the first keyframe and paste it just after the last frame (here, frame 51), delete several keyframes before 151 so that it interpolates. Also delete some frames after frame 0 because the beginning seemed not fluid:

[image]

- It works

Comment: hmm what heppend to me every keyframe after bake disapear,... edit : "did you do in animation tab or layout?"

Comment: all the keyframes disappear after baking? mmh that's weird, make sure the pop-up settings are the same as mine

Comment: ok, did it like you say... i did bake it and did remove cloth modifier ... now i need to make next step like you say... ok thats it... i think now its works properly! thanks alot!

Comment: great then.....    ;)