# Cloth Animation loop

Tags: cloth-simulation

I'm using cloth physics for human body to make jiggles with collision. It looks fine but my problem is animation is not looping it does reset when goes to frame 1. So is there any way to make cloth physics animations loop? And if there is how to stop them restarting and make them loop like gifs. Can you help me?

Comment: Hello, I saw someone doing it this way, a bit tedious though, maybe there's another solution? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/199610/animated-flag-loop?noredirect=1