# How to make the tail of bone to follow a vertex movements?

Tags: animation, bones

Basically I want the tail of my bone to follow a vertex of a mesh when animating. "Copy Location" bone constraint only move the head of the bone, so I can't use that

[image]

Comment: can u tell us a bit more of you "end goal" or what you are really trying to achieve?

Comment: I want "cloth physics" movements in my rig, so I can export that movements to game engine. Because of that I need each point of my rig bones to follow each vertex in my mesh. I just stuck on this part

Comment: in that case maybe this will help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/199610/animated-flag-loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can give your bones a *Stretch To* constraint, create some vertex groups made of one vertex in your plane to make the bones point toward them, set the *Original Lenght* in the constraint in order to make the bone tail stick to its vertex:

[image]