# Is there a way to animate from physics to bone?

Tags: animation, bones, physics

I have a skirt I want to animate, and it has bones.

But, I would rather not animate it by manually moving the bones for every frame of every animation.

Is there a way to animate it with physics, and then use the weight painting to automatically key the bones to the most appropriate location?

Comment: maybe take a look at the method used for a flag: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/199610/animated-flag-loop

Comment: This tutorial from Daniel Kreuter does a similar thing to what you ask, you may want to check it out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A5tEGvRjJO8&t=47s