# Can I affect bones with forcefields or somehow fake noise/turbulence on a group of bones? (animating anemone tentacles)

Tags: animation, bones

I am making an animated GLTF model for use on the web, so actual physics are out of the question I'm afraid, and I'm stuck with armatures (I could be unaware of alternative options though).

Here's a rough test model with bones in tentacles:

[image: test model with bones in tentacles]

Here's what type of movement I'd like to recreate:

[image: real life anemone movement]

Just calmly rotating back and forth but maintaining some form of visual consistency of the motion between tentacles.

[image]

Comment: you could use physics instead of bones, but if you use bones you could give a Noise modifier to the first bone and give a copy rotation to the next ones so that they follow?

Comment: @moonboots 1. how could I export physics into a GLTF model? 2. I also thought of noise modifiers, but I feel like that short idea alone is missing a piece of a puzzle. I don't know how I'd make the rotation act like a noise field where the tentacles clearly follow some sort of, well, noise patterns. Maybe I could somehow animate the bones with proximity based effects and move a bunch of empties around or something?

Comment: If you have only 8 tentacles, you could simply create one animation for a bone chain, then copy paste it for the other chains, change the animations a bit. To save a physic animation here is a solution but it's a bit tedious in my opinion: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/199610/animated-flag-loop

Comment: There's a two-part tutorial on creating robotic arms by PolyFjord [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-2HCxy4Kh4E) which might show you how it can be done with bones. Most of it you can skip over, but it shows you the technique in detail. Basically, you add an empty to the end of the arm and animate that with noise. The section on animating with noise is in Part 2 and starts [here](https://youtu.be/5Wn7gSTay0Y?t=316).

Comment: Honestly, both of your suggestions look super valid! It will take me some time to fully test their limits. I'll return with results, hopefully. Thank you!

Comment: You could also use a Stretch To constraint with noise for the top bone, would you be able to export this constraint? https://zupimages.net/up/22/24/cgnh.gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my question with a method suggested by @moonboots and I expanded it with a script to make it less tedious. [(original tutorial with the method)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r1w4VoVPixg)

**Step 1:** Create an edge and subdivide it. Think of it as mesh-equivalent of your bones.

[image: a subdivided edge]

**Step 2:** Create bones that perfectly cover the segments (use snapping to vertices; use bone subdivision for longer segments)

[image: bones overlapping edge]

**Step 3:** Parent mesh to armature with automatic weights and disable the Armature modifier. This will create vertex groups with bone names. I also added a Pin group to hold my tentacle in place.

[image: vertex groups]
[image: disabled armature modifier]

**Step 4:** You can use this script to add constraints to every bone in your armature. It will add a `Track To` constraint to every bone, set it to track your mesh and for each bone it will set it to track the vertex group of the same name. It assumes `Track Axis: Y` and `Up: Z` are going to work for you.

```
import bpy

#change to your armature's name
armature = 'Armature'

#change to the name of the mesh parented to the armature
mesh = 'Plane.001'

bones = bpy.data.objects[armature].pose.bones

for bone in bones:
    nc = bone.constraints.new(type='TRACK_TO')
    nc.target = bpy.data.objects[mesh]
    nc.subtarget = bone.name
    nc.track_axis = 'TRACK_Y'
    nc.up_axis = 'UP_Z'
    nc.use_target_z = True
```

If you mess up you can clear all constraints with

```
import bpy

#name of your armature
armature = 'Armature'

bones = bpy.data.objects[armature].pose.bones

for bone in bones:
    for constraint in bone.constraints:
        bone.constraints.remove(constraint)
```

[image: script in action]

**Step 5:** Add soft body to the mesh (or cloth--but I can only confirm soft body to allow for collisions of just edges without faces) and simulate. The bones should move together with the mesh.

[image: simulation]

**Step 6:** Now you can bake the animation of selected bones by using *Pose>Animation>Bake Action* (with checked settings from the pic) and you're basically done. From here you can parent any mesh you want to the armature.

[image: how to bake animation]

##### Final thoughts

This method is vulnerable to bones rolling during simulation, I'm not sure if it's possible to do anything about it other than setting `Target Z` on bone constraints. Here's how bad it gets **without** `Target Z`:

[image: bones rolling]

Target Z fixes it, but it still happens from time to time. I tried using `Limit Rotation` constraints but without success.

And lastly, to make an anemone, before adding any constraints you can turn on snapping to faces with rotation and join armature and mesh copies together.

[image: adding multiple tentacles]