# How do I loop a cloth sim for a walk cycle?

Tags: modeling, animation, physics, cloth-simulation

I am using cloth sim to make the cloth of a character a bit more dynamic and I want to render out the character's walk cycle as a seamless loop. However I don't know how I would make the cloth sim for a moving character loop seamlessly? How would I do this?

Comment: I don't think you can unless you convert your cloth simulation to bone keyframes like here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/199610/animated-flag-loop ... or apply as several shapekeys

Comment: although i don't like to disagree with moonboots, but you can. You can use mesh cache and then e.g. keyframe the influence

Comment: @Chris Ok, I'll do some looking around on Mesh Cache and figure out how it works. Is there any sources you'd suggest or how to use it?

Comment: one example video is here: https://youtu.be/ey5QHZkoejE

Comment: Oh OK my bad ;)

Comment: @Chris  I'll try this again, I did look at that video but when it came to offsetting the frames with the MeshSequenceCache the clothing was off frame from the rest of the walk cycle and clipping through the body. Maybe export the whole thing for this method?

Comment: if i were you i would begin with e.g. a simple flag animation and turbulence force field. Then use mesh cache to make it loopable to get comfortable how it works. After that i would try that with your walk cycle. I have no idea what you did and how you did it because you provided nearly zero informations about your settings. So if you wanna have further help, maybe you should provide a blend file.